# Is there a way to add a working scrollbar to my tkinter app without it being linked in a listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I have a label and an entry box in my app
What I want is the scrollbar not being linked to a `listbox` since I don't want to create any

```
mylabel = Label(win, text=text1)
mylabel.pack()

mytext = Entry(win, width=50)
mytext.pack()

sbar=Scrollbar(win)
sbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem with the code you have posted? By the way, you can format your code as 'code' by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-k.

Comment: The scrollbar is not working in this code